# Autoloader registery not found in autoload.php

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I was facing an error while updating my magento 2 website, because of that error i can't able to do anything ex: i can't able to compile, update & deploy static content.

Here is the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Autoload\AutoloaderRe                      gistry' not found in /var/www/vhosts/potboy.com.my/httpdocs/app/autoload.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/potboy.com.my/httpdocs/app/bootstrap.php(30): require_once()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/potboy.com.my/httpdocs/bin/magento(14): require('/var/www/vho                      sts...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/potboy.com.my/httpdocs/app/autoload.php on line 37
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. i already updated the composer but still the same error exists please find this screenshot for reference

[image: screenshot].

here is my autoload file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Register basic autoloader that uses include path
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\Autoload\AutoloaderRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\Autoload\ClassLoaderWrapper;

/**
 * Shortcut constant for the root directory
 */
define('BP', dirname(__DIR__));

define('VENDOR_PATH', BP . '/app/etc/vendor_path.php');

if (!file_exists(VENDOR_PATH)) {
    throw new \Exception(
        'We can\'t read some files that are required to run the Magento application. '
         . 'This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly.'
    );
}

$vendorDir = require VENDOR_PATH;
$vendorAutoload = BP . "/{$vendorDir}/autoload.php";

/* 'composer install' validation */
if (file_exists($vendorAutoload)) {
    $composerAutoloader = include $vendorAutoload;
} else {
    throw new \Exception(
        'Vendor autoload is not found. Please run \'composer install\' under application root directory.'
    );
}

AutoloaderRegistry::registerAutoloader(new ClassLoaderWrapper($composerAutoloader));

// Sets default autoload mappings, may be overridden in Bootstrap::create
\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::populateAutoloader(BP, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Magento not find vendor/magento/framework/Autoload/AutoloaderRegistry.php

Can you check above file is there or not and if not than first run command "composer update" from the root of your Magento installation.

Comment: we already tried composer update, composer install &  composer dump autoload too. Still the same error exists.

Comment: Run command "composer update" in setup folder also as per suggested here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/794